# Can I buy pressure cookers and mixer grinders in Poland?

Tags: europe, food-and-drink, shopping, poland

I am from Kerala, India.
I am going to Poland (Krakow) next week for long term stay.
In our style of cooking, pressure cookers and powerful mixer grinders (for grinding rice, red chillies etc, not for juices) are very important accessories.
I have heard from sources that pressure cookers and mixer grinders are generally not available in Europe and Poland

What is the reality about this ?

Comment: I can't speak for all Europe and it's not definitly the first think I look for when travelling around. but I pay attention if I see a cooking devices shop. It's not widely available in "any corner" but these devices are not hard to find.

Comment: Pressure cookers are considered a bit old-fashioned but can still be found. Automatic rice cookers are also less common than in some other places but not hard to come by. Note that in the worse case you can, easily and legally, order just about everything from Germany or the UK to Poland (i.e. for personal use there are no import duties or extra taxes and delivery costs are completely bearable). Finding some fresh ingredients is likely to be more challenging.

Comment: @Annoyed thanks for the info . "Pressure cookers are considered a bit old-fashioned" - what is modern then ?

Comment: And what about heavy duty mixer grinders ? at our place 700 watts mixer grinders are common but I hear that in Europe the mixers are mostly for making juices

Comment: What's wrong about using a 700w to make juice? You can even use a 1000w for this ...

Comment: Modern would be everything pre-cooked and frozen, I guess ;-) Also many people simply don't have/need a mixer but that's not to say that you cannot find one if you want one. Grinders are also easy to find but mostly intended for coffee, not spices, and what's used to mix fruit is typically called a “blender”. It's true that many models have 400W but 700W (and more) immersion mixers, blenders or food processors are all widely available. Maybe you should just check large retail websites like Amazon and see if you can find what you want.

Comment: Amazon (online shopping)? I know Amazon exists for some parts of Europe. Maybe they would ship to Poland?

Comment: Reminder to closevoters: Just because a question is about shopping, it doesn't make it a question on "price-shopping for specific goods or services".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reasons pressure cookers are not so popular in Poland. It might be related to bad fame they've got following some accidents decades ago. However, they are making their comeback and it's possible to buy them. You can use meta-search to look for *"szybkowar"*, for example http://www.ceneo.pl/Szybkowary.
This is mainly for buying on-line, but many of these stores are physical stores (for example Saturn, Media-Markt, EURO).

Answer (score 8):

The reality is that you will find these devices in Europe. You will have to go to specialised stores, but they are not hard to find, especially in big cities.

Krakow has several shopping malls. There is even one with a "Media Markt",  an electronics superstore with a quite large range of products.

Answer (score 7):

There are tons of this stuff in Poland. You will find just about any brand of desired quality and price ranging from basic to professional. A good idea to start with is www.ceneo.pl which will help you to shop online and compare prices.

Recommended, quality cookware brands in Poland are: Bosch, Zelmer and Braun. They aren't the cheapest but they are worth their price.

Very nice shops online with good prices and great customer service:

www.neo24.pl, www.morele.net, www.x-kom.pl, www.oleole.pl

A few phrases to look after:

garnek do ryżu - rice cooker,
szybkowar - pressure cooker,
blender ręczny - hand blender,
blender stojący - stationary blender,
młynek - grinder

Most cheap cookware is like 250-300 watts. But it isn't really a problem to buy 600-700W blender or even a 1000W one. I personally use Braun and Zelmer and they are exactly like that so you can grind anything you like.